# I did not do all those edits

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits

Looking at the second of [these revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23278452/revisions), the only edit I made was remove the first sentence, but I see two other chunks that were changed. I promise it wasn't me. Also, just after I submitted my edit, I saw a message that said something like *an edit has been made to this post; reload*.

Answer (score 6):

The author of the post edited it, after you started your edit, and within the post's grace period.  Since what you posted was based off of an earlier version, from the point of view of the diff algorithm it looks like you reverted the changes, even though you didn't do so explicitly.

Comment: So, something of a race condition.