# Revision history shows changes in an edit that I did not make

Tags: discussion, edits, grace-period

I'm not sure if this is a bug or something I'm just not understanding properly.  I recently made an edit to a post to inline an image, and improve the grammar (see the 2nd [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48044804/revisions)).  There was some code also in the question, but I did not make any changes to that.

When I looked at the question later, the OP made a revision to it and when I checked on it, I saw that my edit included a small but significant change to two constants in the original code *that I did not make*.  It gives the appearance that I made a bad change to the code.

The OP fixed that in the later edit, but I'm wondering where that extra change came from?  A [quick edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252051/i-did-not-do-all-those-edits) by OP or another user right after my edit that got bundled together as one edit?  Something weird with my browser?  Y2K gremlins, 18 years late?

Comment: Would the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48044804/timeline) have indicated it if there were concurrent edits at (roughly) the same time?

Comment: Most likely explanation is conflicting edits.  You start editing, someone else edits, then you post your edit which was based on the original post, undoing the 2nd edit.  How long did it take you to compose the edit?  Timestamp says you posted it at 18:37Z.  But if you started your edit very early in the post's history (within the first 5 minutes), it is possible the OP edited the post after you started your edit and then your edit undid the OP's updates.

Comment: [Related same experience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324018/how-is-the-order-of-suggested-edits-in-the-review-queue-handled)

Comment: @psubsee2003 It don't think it took me that long, but it's possible I was distracted and let it sit for a while before finishing it up.

Comment: @psubsee2003:  do these concurrent edits *not* get logged, as can be seen in the lack of evidence in the timeline?

Comment: @usr2564301 if it happens within the first 5 minutes and was written by the original poster, no.  Most edits by the OP in the first 5 minute grace period are rolled up into a single edit